# How to set the default zoom of a pdf in qwebengineview on pyside6, I want to be able to zoom the pdf upon launching the viewer

Tags: pyqt, pyside, pyside6, pyqt6

I am loading a pdf in qwebengineview and I want the pdf to automatically zoom to fit the pdf viewer. I have trying using setZoomFactor but it doesn't seem to have any effect. Any suggestions would be helpful, here is minimal working example code:

```
from PySide6.QtCore import *
from PySide6.QtGui import *
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
from gui_elements import back_button_style, submit_button_style
from PySide6.QtWebEngineCore import QWebEngineSettings
from PySide6.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
import sys



app = QApplication(sys.argv)

#temporary pdf viewer
pdf_view = QWebEngineView()
pdf_view.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)
pdf_view.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
pdf_view.settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.PluginsEnabled, True)
pdf_view.settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.PdfViewerEnabled, True)
pdf_view.resize(1300, 800)
pdf_view.load(QUrl.fromLocalFile(filename))

#my attempts
pdf_view.page().setZoomFactor(3.0)
pdf_view.setZoomFactor(3.0)

pdf_view.show()

app.exec()
```

[here is how I want it to open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2et1.png)

I stumbled across another stack overflow post about executing javascript within qwebengineview, and I tried to recreate their example, but I couldn't find the zoom command in the docs, how would I go about finding this?

Comment: That sounds promising, do I just add ‘#zoom=150’ to the end of my qurl or could you give me an example? Thanks

Comment: the "#zoom=" tag works, appreciate you bruv