# Pyqt5 pdf viewer doesn't display zoom buttons or zoom percentage

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm learning how to use pyqt, I'm using Windows 10 and python 3.10 and i'm testing a code to open pdf files, this allows you to select the file and then opens it on a new window. It works almost correctly except that doesn't show zoom buttons, or zoom percentage.

This is the code:

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets


def main():

    print(
        f"PyQt5 version: {QtCore.PYQT_VERSION_STR}, Qt version: {QtCore.QT_VERSION_STR}"
    )

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    filename, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, filter="PDF (*.pdf)")
    if not filename:
        print("please select the .pdf file")
        sys.exit(0)
    view = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
    settings = view.settings()
    settings.setAttribute(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineSettings.PluginsEnabled, True)
    url = QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(filename)
    view.load(url)
    view.resize(640, 480)
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I was wondering if I need to pass an extra setting to display zoom buttons on pdf viewer. Anyone can help me? I highlighted where buttons/actions supposed to display in the image below.

[image: I highlighted where buttons/actions supposed to display]

Comment: This is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72863750/how-to-set-the-default-zoom-of-a-pdf-in-qwebengineview-on-pyside6-i-want-to-be

Comment: You could try the `pdfjs` viewer instead, which has more features. For more details, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48053017/984421).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That problem is because Qt version, if you test with the most recent version, PyQt6 you will see that works.

You need to install PyQt6:

```
pip install pyqt6
```

You also need to install webengine for pyqt6:

```
pip install PyQt6-WebEngine
```

And you need to change your code to this:

```
import sys

from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets


def main():

    print(
        f"PyQt6 version: {QtCore.PYQT_VERSION_STR}, Qt version: {QtCore.QT_VERSION_STR}"
    )

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    filename, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, filter="PDF (*.pdf)")
    if not filename:
        print("please select the .pdf file")
        sys.exit(0)
    view = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
    settings = view.settings()
    settings.setAttribute(view.settings().WebAttribute.PluginsEnabled, True)
    url = QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(filename)
    view.load(url)
    view.resize(640, 480)
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And now should look like this:

[image: loaded pdf]